# Как настроить xdebug + phpstorm на удаленном сервере

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, remote-debugging

Что делал для этого.

1. Для начала установил на сервер xdebug. на centos 6 установил расширение

   yum install php-pecl-xdebug.x86_64

2.настроил php.ini

```
zend_extension = /usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so
zend_extension_ts = /usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.6_ts.so
zend_extension = /usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = myIP
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"
```

На сервере установлен VESTA, как видно из записей, там еще установлен ion_cube

3. На phpstorm настроил удаленный интерпретатор

[image: На phpstorm настроил удаленный интерпретатор]

4. Создал сервер
   [image: Создал сервер]

5 Добавил Deployment по фтп для синхрона и настроил mapping
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

6 Проверил валидацию
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

7. Создал конфигурацию для отладки
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В браузере уже стоит расширение по отлавливанию кода, так как уже работал на локальном сервере.
И .... всё ))) начались танцы с бубнами.
Для начала поставил Break at first line , посмотреть как работает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Реакции 0.
Перекопал весь инет , пробовал. не отлавливает. Мысли были разные, что phpstorm игнорирует удаленный php и слушает локальный, но у расширений разные версии , это видно в скрине, на удаленке 2.5.5 на локальном 2.2.5. Через пару дней поисков ошибки, вспомнил что надо порт для защищенного соединения прописать 443, обрадовался, думал в этом причина, тоже не работает.
Читал что phpstorm не дружит по этому вопросу с https, для проверки сделал новый проект для обычного соединения (есть домен запасной, установил движок на новый сайт, настроил, тоже не работает). Читал про ssh tunnel. Настроил соединение , в putty
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
в php.ini

```
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
```

тоже не работает у меня ((.
Уже от отчаяния смонтировал удаленку к себе на windows, с надеждой запустить дебаг как локально, но что-то не совсем понимаю как это может работать, забросил.
пробовал настроить конфигурацию PHP Web Page, тоже настраивается, но не отлавливает.

Помогите, очень надеюсь что решение где то рядом и я его не вижу.
Чтобы окончательно удостовериться , что на стороне сервера xdebug работает корректно, думаю как посмотреть что расширение xdebug что-то отсылает на порт 9000. Правда не знаю как , в админке не силен ((.
Подскажите куда копать, HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всему виной роутер был, без проброски портов не получается )