# Как настроить XDebug на сером IP в PhpStorm

Tags: docker, phpstorm, xdebug

Настраиваю XDebug в PhpStorm, работаю в нем из дома с серым IP адресом, а веб-сервер работает на удаленной машине, внутри докер-контейнера `php:7.3-fpm-alpine3.9`. Обычно XDebug сидит на 9000 порту, что и php-fpm, поэтому порт Xdebug я назначил на 9009.

Как я понял, XDebug с удаленной машины должен сам постучаться по IP адресу, который указан в `xdebug.remote_host`, но у меня серый IP, поэтому ему это сделать не удастся.

Как это сделать?

Вот что я делал:

1. В настройках PhpStorm есть "Validate debugger configuration on Web Server", я запустил эту проверку, все OK.
2. Поставил расширение в Хром XDebug helper, настроил его на PhpStorm (там ключ "PHPSTORM")
3. Есть еще настройка DBGp Proxy, я сначала думал это использовать, но думаю что это не для этого. Сейчас там ключ: PHPSTORM, хост: 127.0.0.1, порт: 9009
4. Сейчас настройки XDebug такие:

```
idekey=PHPSTORM
remote_port=9009
default_enable=1
remote_enable=1
remote_autostart=1
remote_host=localhost
```

5. В PHPStorm Debug port `9009`, а на вкладке "DBGp Proxy" IDE key: PHPSTORM, host: 127.0.0.1, port: 9009
6. Сделал порт-форвардинг (тут я думаю неправильно сделал, не до конца понимаю как это работает):

```
ssh -R 9009:localhost:9009 username@ip-адрес-веб-сервера
```

Есть [похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1042854/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-xdebug-phpstorm-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5), но он мне не помог.

Answer (score 1):

Вы почти все сделали правильно, однако не все.

Ну смотрите - в силу того что php-fpm у вас крутится в контейнере, то и xdebug стучится в сам контейнер (это конечно при условии контейнер запущен с сетевым драйвером по-умолчанию, а не `host` и это скорее всего именно так) однако ssh -R  подключено к удаленном хосту, а не к контейнеру.

Ваша задача сделать так чтобы xdebug слал данные именно туда, где открыт порт. А значит вам нужно посмотреть какой именно IP у хоста, относительно контейнера и в настройках xdebug в контейнере слать именно туда.

Почти наверняка адрес хоста относительно контейнера 172.17.0.1 , но вы можете запустить на удаленном хосте `docker inspect имяВашегоКонтейнера` и внизу в настройках сети увидите Gateway что и является в нашем случае адрес хоста (относительно контейнера, повторюсь еще раз).

Вот и все. При получении куки - Xdebug начинает слать на 172.17.0.1:9009 где благодаря ssh -R прокинут ваш локальный порт и у вас все работает.

p.s. понятно что при такой структуре вам не нужно менять порт с 9000 на 9009, если конечно у вас на удаленном хосте тоже не крутится php-fpm .